# Integrality of coefficients in some formal power series

Tags: reference-request, formal-power-series

Suppose we have a formal power series $g(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $g(0)=1$. Suppose also that there exists an invertible formal power series $f(x)=x+(\text{higher order terms})$ such that $g(x)g(-f(x))=1$. Is there a known necessary and sufficient condition on $g(x)$ for $f(x)$ to have integer coefficients as well?

Update: if this is too general, we can assume additionally that $g'(0)\ne 0$ as well.

Comment: A formal power series with coefficients in which ring/field?

Comment: Do you mean, for $f$? Probably, $\mathbb{R}$, is general enough, although I think $\mathbb{Q}$ will suffice, too.

Comment: Another problem: $f(x)$ is not an invertible power series, as it has no constant term.

Comment: @Bernard I mean that $f$ has a compositional inverse, not a reciprocal.

Answer (score 2):

We are given that the formal power series (FPS)
$$ g(x) = 1 + c_1\,x + c_2\,x^2 + c_3\,x^3 + \dots \tag{1} $$
has integer coefficients. We are also given that the FPS
$$ f(x) = x + a_2\,x^2 + a_3\,x^3 + \dots \tag{2} $$
satisfies the equations
$$ f(f(x)) = x \tag{3} $$
and
$$ g(x)\,g(-f(x)) = 1. \tag{4} $$
If we assume $\,c_1\ne 0\,$ then the FPS defined by
$$ h(x) := \log(g(x)) \tag{5} $$
also satisfies
$$ h(x) = c_1\,x + O(x^2) \tag{6} $$
and thus has a compositional inverse $\,h^{(-1)}(x).\,$

Taking the logarithm of both sides of equation $(4)$ gives
$$ h(x) + h(-f(x)) = 0. \tag{7} $$
Solving this equation for $\,f(x)\,$ gives
$$ f(x) = -h^{(-1)}(-h(x)) \tag{8} $$
where the first two coefficients are
$$ a_2 = (-c_1^2 + 2\,c_2)/c_1,\quad a_3 = (a_2)^2. \tag{9} $$

Remark: In general, $\,a_n\,$ is a rational function of the
coefficients of $\,g(x)\,$ with denominator $\,c_1^{n-1}\,$ 
and numerator a polynomial with integer coefficients.

If we suppose that $\,|c_1|=1,\,$ then by the previous
remark all of the coefficients of $\,f(x)\,$ are integers.
If we suppose that $\,|c_2|\ge 2,\,$ then determining the
integrality of the coefficients of $\,f(x)\,$ becomes a
much more difficult question.

Remark: Given a solution $\,g(x)\,$ of equation $(4)$
and an integer $\,n\,$, then $\,g(x)^n\,$ is also a
solution with integer coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! This is about where I am now, except I used $G(x)=g(x)-1$ instead of $h(x)=\log(g(x))$ as the function to invert. One sufficient condition on $g(x)$ to ensure the integrality of coefficients of $f(x)$ is if $g(x)=1+ku(x)$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $u(x)=x+\cdots$ has integer coefficients. In that case, $f(x)=u^{\langle-1\rangle}\left(\frac{u(x)}{1+ku(x)}\right)$ has integer coefficients as well. But the example of $(g(x),f(x))=(C^2(x),xC^3(x))$ shows that it is not a necessary condition.